# getClass().getResource() returning null

Tags: java, resources

So, I'm trying to develop a prototype for what may eventually become a game, and I cannot get the images when attempting to access them as a resource, bar one time when it worked.

This is the code:

```
public class Main {
    static boolean finished = false;
    static ArrayList<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battle System Prototype #1");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure to close this window?", "Really Closing?",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });

    frame.addMouseListener(gml);

    Graphic g = new Graphic();
    frame.add(g);

    BufferedImage playerDefault = null;
    BufferedImage monsterDefault = null;
    try {
        playerDefault = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/playerdef.png"));
        monsterDefault = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/monsterdef.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    entities.add(new Player(20, 325, 400, "Player 1", playerDefault, null, null, null, null));
    entities.add(new Player(20, 325, 330, "Enemy", monsterDefault, null, null, null, null));

    while (!finished) {
        g.repaint();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.run();
}
```

}

And this is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at battleSystemPrototype1.Main.run(Main.java:113)
    at battleSystemPrototype1.Main.main(Main.java:133)
```

The /images folder is under the package, so I don't think that is the problem. I suspect that I'm missing something on the syntax, but I don't know what. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: it's the /res folder, not /images, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Post your folder structure please

Comment: /src/packageName/res/playerdef.png and /src/packageName/res/monsterdef.png

Comment: There is nothing to do with [tag:syntax] here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to posting questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your code is in

```
/some/path/src/packageName/Main.java
```

And your images are found in a “res” directory beneath the package directory ...

```
/some/path/src/packageName/res/playerdef.png
/some/path/src/packageName/res/monsterdef.png
```

Then the code:

```
getClass().getResource("/res/playerdef.png")
```

will look for the resource here:

```
[build-destination]/res/playerdef.png
```

Instead, you want:

```
getClass().getResource("res/playerdef.png")
```

Which will search for the resource here:

```
[build-destination]/packageName/res/playerdef.png
```

Note the absence of the leading `/`, which instructs the class loader to begin looking in the root directories of the class path, instead of starting at the current package.

Note:

The above assumes that your particular build environment will copy any resource-type files (such as .png) found inside the src directory tree into a corresponding location in the target build directory structure (actual directories or a jar file).  The exact details will depend on your build tool or IDE.

Comment: It will not look in any `src` directory. It will look along directories named in the CLASSPATH, or in JAR files named in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @EJP I said “_begin looking in root directories of the class path_”. Oh shuzbut! I also gave an absolute path to the source resource and implied the the resource would be found there, trying to show the difference between an absolute path `getResource()` call and a relative one. Fixed.

Comment: This worked, but only after making sure the resources in Eclipse were synced up to the filesystem. Is there any way in Eclipse to make sure the resources used are up to date?

Comment: Right click on the project, and select "Refresh".