# getClass().getResource() always returns null problem

Tags: java, netbeans, null

When I try to get a resource (in this case, an image), it always returns null, even if that resource is in the same package that contains the main class. I'm first trying to make this resource to not be null and that's why I'm using a system.out.println for returning the getClass() value.

I tried this on Netbeans 11.0, tried to Clean and Build, tried to put the resource on different packages (I also was changing the path of the resource on getResource()) and also tried to get the resource of my main class (also got null)

```java
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/logo.png"));
```

I expect to the result being not null, but I guess there's something wrong with the config of NetBeans or something, I'm just a newbie and I'm still learning at this.
Proof that the resource is on the same package as the main method

[image]

Comment: try getClass().getResourceAsStream().

Comment: That won't help!

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. @DenisKokorin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getClass().getResource() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503269/getclass-getresource-returning-null)

Comment: I've actually read the answer given in that post, and that didn't solve my problem either because I think I linked the package correctly (If I'm wrong, please refer to the image to see if I did something wrong.

Comment: The correct name of the resource is either `"logo.png"` if accessed from a class in the same package,  or `"/com/my company/editordetexto/logo.png"` otherwise. `"/logo.png"` cannot possibly be correct for where you have put it.

Comment: Most people put their resources in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: As you're using Maven (assumed from the presence of the `pom.xml` file) you need to put your resources under `src/main/resources`. If you put them under `src/main/java` then Maven will ignore them (by default) and they won't be copied to the output directory, ultimately meaning they don't end up on the classpath. Can't tell what directory you've put the resources in based on the image, but "Source Packages" would seem to be related to `src/main/java` (haven't used NetBeans in a long time).

Comment: Tried to put "logo.png", "/com/mycompany/editordetexto/logo.png", "src/main/resources/logo.png" (on that one I created the resources folder under main because it didn't exist.). but it doesn't make sense to me because I just want to change the favicon of my frame and I watch tutorials on youtube of people doing that with them at the end working but on my side it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe use `logo.png` instead of `/logo.png` (remove the `/`)

Comment: I even tried with a local Windows path: "C:/Users/zelza/OneDrive/Documentos/NetBeansProjects/mavenproject2/EditorDeTexto/src/main/java/com/mycompany/resources/logo.png" and not even that worked.

Comment: @dan1st Already tried that, please read the comments posted earlier.

Comment: Have you tried `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(com/mycompany/editordetexto/logo.png)`? What is the content of `getClass().getClassLoader().getResources()`?